# Not able to Get the response from the function call from Node Js Service Using Web3@1.0.0-beta.36

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain

I am deploying two contracts A and B using Web3(1.0) and solc.
My Solidity file looks something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract A {
   uint public value;
   constructor(uint newValue) public {
        value = newValue;
   }
}

contract B {
   A aObj;

   function setAddress(address _a) public {
       aObj = A(_a);
   }

   //Get Value Function to Return Value
   function getValue() public view returns(uint) {
       return aObj.value();
   }
}
```

I am trying to call the method **getValue()** from Node JS Service as shown below:

```
    //GET Call to Get Value from Contract
app.get("/showMeValue",(req, res) => {
   var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(contractDataB.fileAbiDataContractB,contractAddressB);
   var calculatedGasPrice;
   utils.getGasPrice().then(function(response)
   {
       if(response)
       {
           calculatedGasPrice = response;
           console.log("Calculated Gas Price: "+calculatedGasPrice);
           contractInstance.methods.setAddress(contractAddressA).estimateGas({from: accountAddress}).then(function(gasAmount){
               if(gasAmount <= 2000000)
               {
                   console.log("Gas Amount for Function: "+gasAmount);
                   contractInstance.methods.setAddress(contractAddressA).send({from: accountAddress,gas: gasAmount,gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei(calculatedGasPrice,"Gwei")}).then(function(receipt) {
                       if(receipt) {
                         contractInstance.methods.getValue().call({from: accountAddress}).then(function(response){
                               res.json({"Value":response});
                           }).catch(function(err){
                               console.log(err);
                               res.json({"Error Getting Value":err});
                           });
                       } else {
                           res.json({"Error":"Transaction Not Executed"});
                       }
                   }).catch(function(err){
                       console.log(err);
                       res.json({"Error Setting Address":err});
                   });
               }
           }).catch(function(err){
               res.json({"Error Getting Gas Estimation for Function":err});
           });
       }
   }).catch(function(error){
       res.json({"Error Getting Gas Price":error});
   });
});
```

**utils** is the module created with functions and their promise resolution as I don't want my server file to be too messy.

The Problem what I am facing here is when it calls the function getValue() it gives me an error stating:

```
Response Values Are Not Correct. Did it run out of Gas ?
```

I have been looking for solution and accordingly mentioned the **byzantiumBlock:0** in my genesis.

Still I am facing the issue.

I have tried making two separate contracts and deploying them and then providing the definition of one in the other contract but still the error remains the same.
PS: Everything works smooth in Remix IDE (may be ability to vary gas accordingly).

Does it have anything to do with the gasLimit I have mentioned while setting my local block-chain.

Would like the inputs on this.